# (Recurrence relation) How many subsets of $\{1,2,...,n\}$ exist such that no two elements have a difference of 2?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

Question:
"Find the recurrence relation and starting condition for:
How many subsets of $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ exist such that no two elements have a difference of $2$?"

(This isn't a homework question, I found it while studying for an exam I had and couldn't solve it)

My first intuition was to split the problem to the sets of even and odd numbers, since they don't affect one another in this context, and multiply the results.
But I just couldn't get it into anything close to an answer, I got into an infinite loop and couldn't decide what is the edge case.

Any help or intuition is appreciated.

Comment: Do some samples of small values and look to recognize pattern.  It's easy to see you'll have to do some modified form of stars and bars and if you play you should be able to see what needs modifying.

Comment: @fleablood Thanks, I don't know why but it was so much easier looking at the question:
"How many binary words of $n$ length without 101 and 111 are there?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a_k$ denote the number of subsets with maximal element $k$ such that no two elements have a difference of $2$.
Also define $A_k = \sum_{k' \leq k} a_{k'}$ the number of subsets with maximal element $\leq k$ such that no two elements have a difference of $2$.

Then we have $a_k = A_{k-3} + A_{k-4}$ (the number of subsets containing $k$ but not $k-1$ + that of subsets containing $k$ and $k-1$); and $A_k = A_{k-1} + a_k = A_{k-1} + A_{k-3} + A_{k-4}$

Some explanations:

- $A_{k-1}$: just keep each subset with max element $\leq k-1$ as it is
- $A_{k-3}$: since the subsets contain $k$ but not $k-1$, we cannot have $k-2$ but $k-3$ is fine
- $A_{k-4}$: since the subsets contain $k$ and $k-1$, we cannot have $k-2$ neither $k-3$